# pass data from activity to next activity in android using bundle

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, bundle

I have to pass data from one activity to next activity.

I have used below code on my first activity:

```
   static String KEY_CATEGORY = "Category";
 static final String KEY_TITLE = "Categoryname";
lview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);
         switch (position)
         {
             case Tech:
                 Intent tech = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.SubCate.class);
                 tech.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, "Books");
                 startActivity(tech);   
                 break;
             case Sport:
                 Intent sport = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.SubCate.class);
                 sport.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, "CD-DVD-Video");
                    startActivity(sport);   
                 break;


             default:
                 break;
         }
```

In 2nd activity have to used below code:

```
    static String KEY_CATEGORY = "SubCategory";
 static  final String KEY_SUBCATE = "subcategoryname";
 static final String KEY_TITLE = "Categoryname";
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
     KEY_CATEGORY = bdl.getString(KEY_TITLE);
```

My data have values.
But i have to run the app means am getting empty screen.what am doing wrong here.please help me.

This is full source code:
[MainACtivity.java](http://pastie.org/5493742)

[SubCate.java](http://pastie.org/5493750)

**EDIT:**

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SubCate"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

</application>
```

This is my xml feed:

```
<Feed>
 <category>
  <Category>
      <Categoryname>Books</Categoryname>
          <SubCategory>
          <subcategoryname>Internet</subcategoryname>
          </SubCategory>
          <SubCategory>
          <subcategoryname>Software</subcategoryname>
           </SubCategory>
   </Category>
   <Category> 
        <Categoryname>CD-DVD-Video</Categoryname>
             <SubCategory>
             <subcategoryname>CD</subcategoryname>
             </SubCategory>
              <SubCategory>
              <subcategoryname>DVD</subcategoryname>
              </SubCategory>
   </Category>
   </category>
   </Feed>
```

This is **my expectation output** like:

```
Books
CD-DVD-Video
```

I have to click **Books** means its go to next activity and have to display that books subcategory only.(i.e)i have to click Book category means i have to display Internet and software only.

i have to click **CD-DVD-Video** means its go to next activity and have to display that CD-DVd-Video subcategories only.(i.e)i have to click CD-DVD-Video category means i have to display CD,DVD only.

This is **my current output**:

But i have to run the app means am getting books and cd-dvd-video on first activity.i have to click any category means blank screen is displayed.please help me.what error is occurred here.

**EDIT:**

In these 2nd activity(**SubCate.java**) file i have removed below line

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();  
KEY_CATEGORY = bdl.getString(KEY_TITLE);
```

after i have to run the app means i have displayed Books CD-DVD-Video category on first page.after that i have to click any category means i have displayed all subcategories on each category list.

FOR EG:

i have to click **Book** category means i have to display Internet and software only.but here displayed internet,software,cd,dvd.
and also i have to click **CD-DVD-Video** category means i have to display CD,DVD only.But here also displayed 4 subcategories.what is wrongly done here.please help me.

Comment: do you enter second file activity in manifeast file ?

Comment: ya i have added in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Use getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);

Comment: If are u free then send me your code on this link i slove your problem.http://pastie.org/4795861

Comment: @NiravRanpara here the app is doesn't force closed.i have to click any category means it is go to next activity and have displayed blank screen.

Comment: @user1859172 Please give more information.

Comment: @user1859172 witch link?

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh please see my updated question and give me solution for this

Comment: @user1859172 can you share your manifest file here? I think your both activity code looks fine.

Comment: Simple Remove your package name from intent.Intent tech = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.SubCate.class); com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue this. ok and you don`t get any error.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh I have removed my package name from my intent activity class.now also am getting blank screen only

Comment: @user1859172 : yes you are not passing right TAG pass "Categoryname" instead of "Books" from   MainActivity Activity

Comment: Hi  static final String KEY_TITLE = "Categoryname";    here Categoryname only assign to KEY_TITLE.then it is correct TAG only.if i have any mistake means let me know

Answer (score 1):

change the name of the activity in the manifest file as follows:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".SubCate"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Activity:

```
lview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        //HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);
     switch (position)
     {
         case Tech:
             Intent tech = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubCate.class);
             tech.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, "Books");
             startActivity(tech);   
             break;
         case Sport:
             Intent sport = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubCate.class);
             sport.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, "CD-DVD-Video");
                startActivity(sport);   
             break;


         default:
             break;
     }
```

In your second activity do as follows:

```
String key = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
```

Comment: @user1859172 : how you known you are not getting data from one Activity. just post your xml. i'm sure you are not passing right TAG for parsing

Comment: please check my edited question and give me solution for this

Comment: @Nunu now i have changed my manifest file and add these line on my 2nd activity also.now i have to run the app means am getting Books and CD-DVD-Video .if i have to click any category means have displayed all subcategories on each category.but i wish to click any category means am getting subcategory belongs to category.For eg:i have to click Book category means i have to display Internet and software only.but here displayed 4 internet,software,cd,dvd.also i have to click CD-DVD-Video category means i have to display CD,DVd only.But here also displayed 4 subcategories.what is wrongly done here

Answer (score 0):

just do ad follow

Intent i = getIntent();

```
if(i != null){

   String Title = i.getExtra.getString(KEY_TITLE);
```

}

Comment: Really mind blowing answer, if intent is null then how you can get value from intent.

Comment: but this is not answer because  code for sending value from one activity to second activity is right if he is sending static value.problem is somewhere in xml parsing. may be he is not sending right XML TAG